# VS does not see my Android 4.4.2 phone

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am writing my first Xamarin application. I want to test run it on my phone Samsung Galaxy 3 (Android 4.4.2 Kit Kat) but it doesn't appear among the VS project build options. I have set the target platform to Android 7.1 and the minimal Android version to 4.0. Has anybody have any similar experiences? How did you fix it?

Comment: Do you have developer mode enabled on your phone?  Do you have the correct drivers installed on your machine?

Comment: As add up remember to enable developer mode on windows _**IF**_ you're using Windows 10

Comment: Yes, I have enabled developer mode. I do have all the necessary drivers

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin has great documentation, tutorials, and code samples.

Here's a detailed guide to setting up your device for development:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/set_up_device_for_development/

A gotcha that might cause this issue is bad project configuration. Open the configuration manager in VS and look at your current settings for your Xamarin Forms and Android projects (I think it's ARM for the S3--not x86).

Comment: I have followed this exact tutorial and it's still not working.

Comment: Someone on the Xamarin forums linked to Samsung's developer drivers for the S3: https://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/galaxy-s-iii-developer-edition-verizon


Also, I've been tripped up a few times where I didn't see my device because configuration was set incorrectly.  Open the configuration manager in VS and look at your current settings for your Xamarin Forms and Android projects (I think it's ARM for the S3--not x86).  If not set correctly, that might cause the issue you're having.